# How to handle button click event from form1 in form2

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have two forms:

**Form1.cs**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1    
    {
        public partial class Form : System.Windows.Forms.Form
        {
            Form2 form2;

            public Form()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                form2 = new Form2(this);
            }
        }        
        public void buttonCalculate2axis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // some code - it isn't important
        }
}
```

**Form2.cs**

```
Namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form2 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    Form form1;
    public Form2(Form data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form1 = data;
    }        
    private void Form2_VisibleChanged(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    // some code - it isn't important
    }
}
```

I'm trying use the event `public void buttonCalculate2axis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` from **Form1** in **Form2**. So if i push the button in **Form1**, in **Form2** i will waiting for this event and after that i can go next in code.
And if its possible i woun't use the `private void Form2_VisibleChanged(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)` only the click event.

Comment: Where are you trying to attach the `buttonCalculate2axis_Click` handler? You should be able to attach it just like any other method. Also, `buttonCalculate2axis_Click` isn't an event; it's just a method that has the signature of an event handler.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this, are you specifically wanting to attach and event handler that lives on `Form2` to the event that originates in `Form1`?  Or are you just wanting to be able to react to that event somehow?

Comment: I need react to button event from form1 in form2. i want use `buttonCalculate2axis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { //some code } ` in form2 and delete `private void Form2_VisibleChanged(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form with the button has a reference to the form with the handler, and that handler is `public`, then you can just [dynamically bind an event handler in code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3d01ft1.aspx):

```
someButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(otherForm.SomeClickHandler);
```

In your code it looks like the click handler is *in* `Form1`, and since you claim that the button is also in `Form1`, so it's not clear what *exactly* you need to do here.  But if you have a `public` handler in `Form2` then you can use `form2.YourHandlerFunction` as the event handler.

Or if `Form2` instead has the button and you want to use the handler in `Form1` then `Form2` would use the above code with `form1. buttonCalculate2axis_Click` as the event handler.

Comment: Because when you run app you can see window **Form1**, you fill the inputs and push the button. After this you got new Window **Form2**. When you don't close second window and push button again i can't update data in second window. Because handler ChangeVisible is only when you call Show() and Hide()

Comment: @JiříVyplašil: So... Is this failing in some way?

Comment: no button is only in form1 with handler and data for update its in form2

Comment: @JiříVyplašil: So what did you try based on this answer?  `Form1` has a reference to an instance of `Form2`, so once that instance exists then any public click handler method on `Form2` can be added to the `Click` event of the button on `Form1`.  It's really difficult to discern *specifically* what you need to do since (1) your code doesn't even compile and (2) you keep talking about using an event handler in `Form2` but in your code the event handler is in `Form1`.

Comment: Sorry, for me is hard to explain you. So but i try your solution but when i want compile i got error `Form2 variable is not declared or it has not yet been assigned a value.` and i add in **Form1.Designer.cs**  `buttonCalculate2axis.Click += new System.EventHandler(form2.clickEvent);` and in **Form2.cs** i have `public void clickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: @JiříVyplašil: Why did you add it in the *designer*?  You need to use the `form2` variable where that variable *exists*.  (And has been initialized.)  Right after the line `form2 = new Form2(this);` seems like a good place.